# Broken Access Control / Broken Authorization using ASP.NET_SessionId

Tags: security, owasp, websecurity

My client's security team recent told us, our website has Broken Authorization.

Our website built on asp.net and iis.

The website is instranet only and has a strong password policy, MFA, HTTPS, cookies need SSL, CORS setup, but the security team was able to get response by copying the whole cookies and placing it to another user's login session using Burp Suite.

I wonder whatelse my team can do to prevent it.

Really need a help.....

Thanks.